# Why did Rijndael become AES; what is wrong with Twofish and Serpent?

Tags: aes, serpent, twofish

Why did the Rijndael cipher become the Advanced Encryption Standard instead of Twofish and Serpent?
Do Serpent and Twofish have security issues or weak keys?
Or is it just slower?
I know that some modern cryptography programs use twofish and serpent?

Sorry for the dumb question .